# Find the tangent plane of a 2 variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $ f (x,y) = sin(ax + y^2)$ with $ a \in R$

Find the value of $a$ such that the tangent plane to the graph of $f$ in the point $(0,\sqrt\pi,0)$ goes through the point $(1,\sqrt\pi,5)$

Solution:

The tangent plane of $f$ exists so $f$ is differentiable which means that $f$ can be written as:

$ f (\overrightarrow{x}) = f(\overrightarrow{x_0}) + <\overrightarrow{m},\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x_0}> + o(||\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x_0}||)$

where

$y = f(\overrightarrow{x_0}) + <\overrightarrow{m},\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x_0}>$ is the equation of the tangent plane of $f$ in the point $(\overrightarrow{x_0},f(\overrightarrow{x_0})$

and

$m = \nabla f(\overrightarrow{x_0})$

So $\overrightarrow{x_0} = (0,\sqrt\pi)$ :

$ f (\overrightarrow{x_0}) = 0$

and

$\nabla f(\overrightarrow{x}) = (a cos(ax+y^2),2ycos(ax+y^2),0)$

$m = \nabla f(\overrightarrow{x_0}) = (-a,-2\sqrt\pi,0)$

Considering $\overrightarrow{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ I have:

$y = f(\overrightarrow{x_0}) + <\overrightarrow{m},\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x_0}>$

$5 = 0 + <(-a,-2\sqrt\pi,0),(x_1,x_2-\sqrt\pi,x_3)>$

$5 = -ax_1 - 2x_2\sqrt\pi + 2\pi$

$5 = -a - 2\sqrt\pi\sqrt\pi + 2\pi$

$a = -5$

The value of $a$ is right, I would like to know if I solved it in the right way

Comment: Your gradient is not correct. You should write the surface equation as $\sin(ax+y^2)-z=0$. Then it suffices to express that the vector defined by the two given points is perpendicular to the gradient: $(1,0,5)\cdot(-a,-2\sqrt\pi,-1)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal at $p$ is $\nabla f=(a\cos(ax+y^2),\cos(ax+y^2)2y,-1)$ at $p$. Plug in $p=(0,\sqrt{\pi},0)$,we get normal $n=(-a,-2\sqrt{\pi},-1)$.

set the tangent plane as $ax+2\sqrt{\pi}y+z=d$, since $p$ is on the plane, we have $d=2\pi$.
Then since $(1,\sqrt{\pi},5)$ is on the plane, we get $a=-5$

Answer (score 0):

Note that point in a graph is $$ F : (x,y)\in {\bf R}^2 \rightarrow
(x,y,f(x,y)=\sin\ (ax+y^2) \in {\bf R}^3$$

Hence two vectors in tangent plane are $$ F_x=(1,0, f_x)=(1,0,\cos\
(ax+y^2)a)=(1,0,-a),$$ $$ F_y=(0,1,f_y)=(0,1,\cos\
(ax+y^2)(2y)=(0,1,-2\sqrt{\pi})
$$

Hence $$ F_x\times F_y=(-f_x,-f_y,1)=(a,2\sqrt{\pi},1) $$ is normal
to the plane. Hence we have $$ a(x-0) +2\sqrt{\pi}(y-\sqrt{\pi})
+1(z-0)=0$$

Note that this plane passes through given point : $$a=-5$$